# Access PictureBox from Another Form C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing, picturebox

I'm using WinForms. I'm have 2 forms. In form1 i have a picturebox and in form2 i have a button that prints. I'm trying to build an application that will print the images from the picturebox in Form1 using Form2.

I first tried making a panel and testing if the pictures would print in form1, and it did, but the problem is when copied the printing code to form2, the code wouldn't let me access the picturebox in form1.

How do i access the picturebox in Form1 from Form2 so i cant print the images in the picturebox.

I receive error lines under this.pictureBox1.

**Form2**

```
    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
       var bmp = new Bitmap(this.pictureBox1.Width, this.pictureBox1.Height);
       this.pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, this.pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
       e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 25, 25, 800, 1050);
    }
```

Comment: you are in form2. so `this.pictureBox1` refers to the picture box in form 2. you have to make pictureBox1 public and use it in form2

Comment: Its not a duplicate.

Comment: and create a instance of form1 in form2? @M.kazemAkhgary

Comment: the bad suggestion is to make your picturebox `public static`. but i think you shouldnt be worry about that since you only have that two forms.

Comment: I don't fully understand how static works yet. Still new to this. Your solution is working though.

Comment: `static` means one for all instances(lets say always one even if there is no instance). so if you create another instance of `form1` the picturebox is same as picturebox in first `form1`. in other words `static` does not rely on instances.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it :) @M.kazemAkhgary

Comment: See also the numerous other related/duplicate questions on Stack Overflow, including e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/21022854, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1665533, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/11069508 (just to name a few).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your PictureBox from Form1 available to Form2 by passing a reference to it as a property.

I'm not sure how you have your forms set up for loading. But if you are using a Main form that manages Form1 and Form2 you can do something like the following. If you do not have a Main form then this should at least get you on the right track.

**Form1**

```
public PictureBox ThePicture
{
    get {return this.pictureBox1; }
}
```

**Form2**

```
private PictureBox _thePicture;
public PictureBox ThePicture
{
    set { this._thePicture = value; }
    get { return this._thePicture; }
}

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
   if (this.ThePicture != null)
   {
       var bmp = new Bitmap(this.ThePicture.Width, this.ThePicture.Height);
       this.ThePicture.DrawToBitmap(bmp, this.ThePicture.ClientRectangle);
       e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 25, 25, 800, 1050);
   }
}
```

**Main Form**

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.ThePicture = form1.ThePicture;
```

Comment: In  var bmp = new Bitmap(this.ThePicture.Width, this.ThePicture.Height); I keep getting on this.ThePicture i get red error lines. The property or indexer 'PrinterForm.ThePicture' cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor

Comment: Ah, right, I added the missing GET to Form2 ThePicture. You could also just reference the _thePicture variable directly from within printDocument1_PrintPage. Example: `var bmp = new Bitmap(this._thePicture.Width, this._thePicture.Height);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do so:

```
//Tente fazer assim:
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Image getImagePic
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.pictureBox1.Image;
        }

    }
```